# Adding a Progress Indicator when changing Tabs in Flutter

Tags: flutter, tabs

On one of my screens, I use a TAB BAR. Each tab corresponds to one way a list of items should be presented. It is a list of words (English and French translation). The first Tab corresponds to Alphabetical order. The second to Grammar categories (nouns, adverbs...) and the third shows the words by level of difficulty.
I have no problem for generating the lists etc... but when there are a lot of words, there is a delay for the screen to change when you swipe the screen or click on the tab...
Is there a way to add a progress indicator to show the user the app is computing and getting the screen ready ?

What I would need, is a way to detect when the user taps the tab or swipes the screen. Tabs do not seem to function like other buttons.

Here is some part of the code :

```
          bottom: TabBar(
              controller: _controller,
              indicatorWeight: 10,
              indicatorColor: Colors.green[800],
              tabs: [
                Tab(
                  child: Text(
                    'Ordre alphabétique',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red[800]),
                  ),
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: Text(
                    'Catégorie grammaticale',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red[800]),
                  ),
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: Text(
                    'Niveau',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red[800]),
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: _controller,
          children: [
            // Ecran par ordre alphabétique
            ListView(children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: WordListCard(
                  taille: lP.generatedList.length,
                  titre: lP.selectedTheme != ''
                      ? lP.selectedTheme.toUpperCase()
                      : lP.selectedSubtheme.toUpperCase(),
                  mots: ListView.builder(
                   
                      itemCount: lP.generatedList.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index2) {
                        return ListTile(
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                          title: DicoListViewWordCard(
                            number: index2 + 1,
                            main: lP.dicoLanguage == Language.english
                                ? wordBank[lP.generatedList[index2]].main
                                : wordBank[lP.generatedList[index2]].mainFr,
                            trad: lP.dicoLanguage == Language.english
                                ? wordBank[lP.generatedList[index2]].mainFr
                                : wordBank[lP.generatedList[index2]].main,
                            onPress: null,
                          ),
                        );
                      }),
                ),
              ),
            ]),

            // ECRAN par catégorie grammaticale

            ListView(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: DicoListGrammarCard(
                    taille: lP.generatedList.length,
                    tailleNouns: lP.nounList.length,
                    tailleAdj: lP.adjectiveList.length,
                    tailleVerbs: lP.verbList.length,
                    tailleAdv: lP.adverbList.length,
                    taillePrep: lP.prepList.length,
                    titre: lP.selectedTheme != ''
                        ? lP.selectedTheme.toUpperCase()
                        : lP.selectedSubtheme.toUpperCase(),
                    nouns: ListView.builder(
                        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: lP.nounList.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index1) {
                          return ListTile(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                            title: DicoListViewWordCard(
                              number: index1 + 1,
                              main: lP.dicoLanguage == Language.english
                                  ? wordBank[lP.nounList[index1]].main
                                  : wordBank[lP.nounList[index1]].mainFr,
                              trad: lP.dicoLanguage == Language.english
                                  ? wordBank[lP.nounList[index1]].mainFr
                                  : wordBank[lP.nounList[index1]].main,
                            ),
                          );
                        }),
                    adj: ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        itemCount: lP.adjectiveList.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context2, index2) {
                          return ListTile(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                            title: DicoListViewWordCard(
                              number: index2 + 1,
                              main: lP.dicoLanguage == Language.english
                                  ? wordBank[lP.adjectiveList[index2]].main
                                  : wordBank[lP.adjectiveList[index2]].mainFr,
                              trad: lP.dicoLanguage == Language.english
                                  ? wordBank[lP.adjectiveList[index2]].mainFr
                                  : wordBank[lP.adjectiveList[index2]].main,
                            ),
                          );
                        }),
                    verbs: ListView.builder(
                        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: lP.verbList.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context3, index3) {
                          return ListTile(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                            title: DicoListViewWordCard(
                              number: index3 + 1,
                              main: lP.dicoLanguage == Language.english
                                  ? wordBank[lP.verbList[index3]].main
                                  : wordBank[lP.verbList[index3]].mainFr,
                              trad: lP.dicoLanguage == Language.english
                                  ? wordBank[lP.verbList[index3]].mainFr
                                  : wordBank[lP.verbList[index3]].main,
                            ),
                          );
                        }),
                    adv: ListView.builder(
                        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: lP.adverbList.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index2) {
                          return ListTile(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                            title: DicoListViewWordCard(
                              number: index2 + 1,
                              main: lP.dicoLanguage == Language.english
                                  ? wordBank[lP.adverbList[index2]].main
                                  : wordBank[lP.adverbList[index2]].mainFr,
                              trad: lP.dicoLanguage == Language.english
                                  ? wordBank[lP.adverbList[index2]].mainFr
                                  : wordBank[lP.adverbList[index2]].main,
                            ),
                          );
                        }),
                    prep: ListView.builder(
                        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: lP.prepList.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index2) {
                          return ListTile(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                            title: DicoListViewWordCard(
                              number: index2 + 1,
                              main: lP.dicoLanguage == Language.english
                                  ? wordBank[lP.prepList[index2]].main
                                  : wordBank[lP.prepList[index2]].mainFr,
                              trad: lP.dicoLanguage == Language.english
                                  ? wordBank[lP.prepList[index2]].mainFr
                                  : wordBank[lP.prepList[index2]].main,
                            ),
                          );
                        }),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
 bool _load = false;

 void onClick() {
   setState(() {
     _load = true;
   });

   yourFunctionCode;

   setState(() {
     _load = false;
   });
 }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _load
        ? Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        )
        : Container()
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is with Tab Bar : I can't find a way to detect the "onclick"...

Comment: I can see that you have 2 tabs. It is a good practice to break the code in different widgets. Create 2 new files and create statefulwidgets. use the above method in both the widgets.